# Make pip install specific version of dependency package over installing latest

Tags: python, pip

I have a requirements.txt with packages `a` and `b`.

- `a` has a dependency called `c` with the constraint `c==2.3.0`
- `b` has the same dependency but has the constraint `c>=1.2`

If `c`'s latest version available is `4.0`, pip is installing that. But, I need pip to install `2.3.0` How can I make pip do that?

Comment: You probably want to add a [`constraints.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) file with an entry for package `c`

Answer (score 2):

You just specify the version:

`pip install c==2.3.0`

Or, in this case, just install `a` before `b`, since `2.3.0 >= 1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install c==2.3.0
```

Above command helps the pip to install package c of version 2.3.0.